# Surfaces (with boundary) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ conformal to the cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the usual cylinder $S^1 \times [0, 1]$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am interested in knowing what are the surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are conformal to this cylinder. If this were a closed surface, I would know how to attack the problem. One of my aims is to get a better understanding of the "Uniformization theorem" in different settings.

Edit: By two diffeomorphic surfaces $(M_1, g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$ ($g_i$ are metrics) being conformal, I mean $g_2 = e^\phi g_1$. As far as I can see, this does not necessarily have to extend to a conformal transformation of the ambient space.

Comment: What is your definition of a surface conformal to the given? Locally, globally, with respect to the ambient transformation? E.g. all surfaces intrinsically will be locally conformally equivalent. On the other hand, all ambient conformal transformations (i.e. of $\mathbb{R}^3$) will be compositions of translations, dilations and inversions.

Comment: Are you sure you want to consider surfaces with boundary instead of not-necessarily-compact-surfaces-without-boundary such as $S^1 \times (0,1)$? The uniformization refers to surfaces without boundary traditionally (though they may be non-compact).

Comment: Ignoring the boundary, every such surface is conformally equivalent to some annulus $r<|z|<R$. The ratio $R/r$ is  determined by the surface, and describes its conformal class. The conformal map extends to a homeomorphism of the boundaries when the boundaries are Jordan curves (Caratheodory's theorem).